# Install Qt with Cocoa

Tags: qt, macos

I uninstalled my Qt set up and reinstalled with the latest 4.7.1 on my Mac running Snow Leopard using the Cocoa version of Qt from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/qt-for-open-source-cpp-development-on-mac-os-x (Cocoa binary package)

However, I seem to be still running the Carbon version:

```
$ otool -L /Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui
/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/QtGui:
    QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.1)
    QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 152.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1038.32.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 625.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 227.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.29.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 38.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 751.29.0)
```

How can I get the Cocoa version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [4.5 changelog](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/changes/changes-4.5.0):

> Added support for Qt to use Cocoa as
>   its backend instead of Carbon. This is
>   primarily for 64-bit applications, but
>   is also available for 32-bit
>   frameworks as well. 32-bit is still
>   Carbon by default. Passing a 64-bit
>   architecture or -cocoa on the
>   command-line will build Qt against
>   Cocoa. Using Cocoa requires Mac OS X
>   10.5 (or higher) and cannot be used with the -static nor -no-frameworks
>   option. The define QT_MAC_USE_COCOA is
>   available when Qt is built against
>   Cocoa.

Comment: So the dependency on Carbon I see in the output of otool is for the 32 bit version of Qt. The QtGui framework is a universal binary with both 32 bit and 64 bit versions. When I try otool again with '-arch all', why can't I see a Cocoa dependency for the 64 bit version ?

Comment: That is confusing. I would also have expected to see Cocoa dependencies for x86_64, given this should be a binary built against -cocoa.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Cocoa is primarily AppKit and Foundation frameworks; you can see them in the output of otool above. I didn't know that, that's why I'm using QT.